# Online web store + eBay Motors and Amazon integration

Tags: web-apps, ecommerce, amazon, ebay

I'm wondering if such a software exists which primarily is an online commerce store. Inventory is managed primarily through this store (quantity, price, new products, etc.) and can be changed manual via a web interface or managed via an excel sheet upload.

The site would then interface with web services such as Amazon, eBay, and eBay Motors such that everything listed on my primary independent web store is also pushed to Amazon, eBay, and eBay motors. As quantity and price is uploaded and updated on my primary site the updates also get pushed to my Amazon and eBay stores.

I've come across sites like [sellbrite](http://www.sellbrite.com), [volusion](http://www.volusion.com), and big commerce but none of them offer features that fully integrate into the site and especially work with **eBay Motors**.

Does something like this exist or should I be at the patent office?

Answer (score 1):

I did research about webshops and found that Magento seems the best choice. Did you look at [Magento](http://magento.com/) ? It's PHP with rdbms backend. There are also other similar project, but AFAIK magento is the best, since it is the most mature and has the most complete set of functions and interoperability with other vendors, if you want to host your own webshop and can run PHP. There are also other similar projects if you want to make more research:

http://www.satchmoproject.com/
 - [Django-Shopkit](http://dokterbob.github.com/django-shopkit/)
 - [Django Shop](https://www.django-shop.org)
 - [Satchless](http://satchless.com/)
 - [Cartridge](http://cartridge.jupo.org/) (coupled with Mezzanine CMS)
 - [Oscar](http://tangentlabs.github.com/django-oscar/)

I didn’t try them all. See also http://www.readncode.com/blog/the-state-of-ecommerce-in-django/ http://plata-django-shop.readthedocs.org

Comment: Can you add anything about why it is the best?

Comment: And while on it, explicitly state how it meets the OP's requirements? Does "other vendors" include those the OP named? Does maintenance work as described?

Comment: I did research and devlopment for webshops in 2011-2012. The choices were limited. My employer decided to develop inhouse in python. That was a too large project when he also wanted to supply his customers with webhops of their own. Another employer I had was and is using Magento and he is happy with it. I can get more information from actual management (because I'm just the tech dude and not end user or management). If you like you could also have a look at [more choices listed in wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_shopping_cart_software).